# My HTML is not reading the Javascript file in codeacademy editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning some **jquery** using **codeacademy** and while everything works great within the codeacademy editor, it doesn't work when I upload to a server.

Here is the html in question:

```
www.arbabmazumdar.com/kudos.html
```

and here is the *js*:

```
www.arbabmazumdar.com/Web_Files/test.js
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Web_Files/test.js"></script>
```

You don't actually need the `..` part as resources are loaded relatively (i.e. from the same "directory") to the HTML file. `Web_Files/test.js` would be enough.

2) Your file loads just fine, but you didn't include jQuery, so it fails:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined test.js:88
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined kudos.html:19
```

When something doesn't work it's good to check for errors in the JavaScript console(using Firebug, Chrome Dev tools or IEs Developer Toolbar, etc.)

Comment: the JavaScript console is a gem...didn't know about it before. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not yet included jQuery !

Include this in `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
in `<head></head>`